# Solutions to a modified Bessel equation with a weight

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, bessel-functions

A research problem led me to consider the following modification of Bessel's equation:
$$
- \xi''(r) - \frac{N - 1}{r} \xi'(r) - \left(f(r) - \frac{\theta}{r^2} \right)\xi(r) = 0 \quad \text{in} \quad [0, 1]
$$
with boundary conditions
$$
\xi'(0) = 0, [\xi(1) = 1 \text{ or } \xi'(1) = 0].
$$

Of course some hypotheses on $f$ are required, but I can adapt the problem to them.

> Is there any theory regarding such equations with the term $f(r)$ in place of $1$? Any reference? In fact, it would suffice to have some information on $\xi'(1)$ or $\xi''(1)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $f$ is analytic, then power-series solutions exist for the DE.